# I seemed to have deleted my kernel pae headers how do I recover?

Tags: 10.04, kernel

I accidentally deleted the live kernel headers with pae while cleaning my old kernel headers. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 Netbook Remix. How can I recover. I booted with my USB loaded with Ubuntu and all data is intact. Urgent help is required...

Answer (score 2):

Boot with your live USB, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo chroot <the_path_where_your_filesystem_is>
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get check
```

If no errors are provided, try:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Then restart your system without the live USB.